# Failure in verification of Move Module for SUI

Tags: move-lang, sui

So I was following the [documentation for beginners on SUI](https://docs.sui.io/build/move/write-package), I faced an issue with my Move.toml as I was building my file with `sui move build`. And I got the following error

```
Failed to verify the Move module, reason: "Sui framework version mismatch detected.
Make sure that you are using a GitHub dep in your Move.toml:[dependencies]
Sui = { git = \"https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git\", subdir = \"crates/sui-framework\", rev = \"devnet\" }\n`                   
If that does not fix the issue, your `sui` binary is likely out of date--try 
cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet sui".
```

I get that my SUI binary is likely out of date and I tried
`cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet sui`

However that didn't fix the error and I got another error which was

```
error: could not find `sui` in https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet with version `*`
```

I have also tried running the command

```
cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch "devnet" sui sui-gateway
```

From the docs but i am facing this error

```
Updating git repository `https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git`
error: could not find `sui` in https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet with version `*`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git`
error: could not find `sui-gateway` in https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet with version `*`
     Summary Failed to install sui, sui-gateway (see error(s) above).
error: some crates failed to install
```

I am wondering how I can fix the issue and update my sui binary?

Context:
MacOs
SUI before 0.11 devnet release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same errors when trying to install the SUI binaries. The following hint in the [installation instructions](https://docs.sui.io/build/install#install-sui-binaries) solved my issue.

"Trouble shooting: If the previous command fails, make sure you have the latest version of Rust installed:"

```
rustup update stable
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Sui module from Github instead of the local. In your `Move.toml` file

Replace this row

```
[dependencies]    
Sui = { local = "../../../crates/sui-framework" }
```

with this

```
[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework/packages/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
```

When you build for mainnet contract, you should set "rev" to mainnet instead of devnet

It worked well in my side